# Global exception handler for Java 1.4

Tags: java

Is there a way to catch all the exception which haven't been handled in Java 1.4.Kind of a global exception handler of the entire application in Java 1.4

Comment: I'm pretty sure Java 1.4 is deprecated... you might want to look into moving away from it if you can

Comment: Yes. *How* you would do that depends greatly on what framework(s) you're using to run your application. But you're going to be fairly limited in what you can do given that you're using such an ancient version of Java.

Comment: Its a web based application

Comment: That doesn't really help much... but ultimately whatever you're using it's likely to boil down to putting a simple `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { ... }` block at the right place in your application's code, perhaps in some form of interceptor method or filter chain.

Comment: If I may ask, what's the reason you're still using Java 1.4?

Comment: Java 4 has been end of life since October 2008! Why are you using software that has not, and will not be, updated for twelve years?

Comment: Yes.This application was written almost 13 years ago .Why its not been updated I really cant tell .This application will be replaced by a new one in coming days

Comment: You need to be bit more specific, it this a stand-alone application with a `main` method or a web app. As @JonK mentioned you need to add a `try...catch` block around you application's entry point.

Comment: Its web app with 30+ links available in home page.Those 30+ are some way attached to around 700 methods .Out which only 150 have some kind of try and catch.So I was hoping if there a way to catch the exception of the rest of 550 method .Since the application will not be used that much after couple of months so I was hoping to put a generic message for uncaught exception